# How to resolve a 404 error for a asp.net web api deployed to a local file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, deployment, swagger-ui

So I have a web api project that runs perfectly locally (swagger page opens up) however when I deploy it to a local file and try to run it through IIS I get a 404 page error. I’ve looked through several documents but can’t seem to find a fix for this issue

Comment: what's `local file` ? How do you deploy? What URL you are browsing?

Comment: I deployed with Visual studio 2022 to a local folder*.  browsing with localhost

Answer (score 0):

These are the swagger options and when you deploy your site must change "SwaggerEndPoint".

[image]